# Android Eclipse: database doesn't seem to work when APK is installed to an external device

Tags: android, database, eclipse, apk

I am a beginner mobile developer and I am developing a directory app using eclipse for android. I am not really good in coding and programming so I really need help.

My app works good in my laptop, in eclipse emulator but when I run it in my phone, or manually copy the apk and install it in my phone, the app works from the login activity, but when I start searching in the main activity, nothing happens, **no error warning**, **no logcat error** or anything else.

I'm suspecting that the database isn't installed together with the apk, I have no idea what's happening and what to do, please help. Thanks in advance.

```
package samples.planholderdirectory;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "planholder";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /*
         * Create the planholder table and populate it with sample data.
         */
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planholder (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                        "firstName TEXT, " +
                        "lastName TEXT, " +
                        "contractNo TEXT, " +
                        "plan TEXT, " +
                        "description TEXT, " +
                        "effectivity TEXT, " +
                        "dueDate TEXT, " +
                        "quotaComm TEXT, " +
                        "quotaNComm TEXT, " +
                        "CBI TEXT, " +
                        "instNo TEXT, " +
                        "aging TEXT, " +
                        "balance TEXT, " +
                        "taxable TEXT, " +
                        "insured TEXT, " +
                        "orNo TEXT, " +
                        "orDate TEXT, " +
                        "collDue TEXT, " +
                        "collAdvance TEXT, " +
                        "managerId INTEGER)";
db.execSQL(sql);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

This is my DatabaseHelper

```
package samples.planholderdirectory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class PlanholderList extends ListActivity {

    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);    
    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite and for lpa number
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, contractNo FROM planholder WHERE contractNo || ' ' || firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                        new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.planholder_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"contractNo", "firstName", "lastName"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.contractNo, R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlanholderDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("PLANHOLDER_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

this is my PlanholderList

```
package samples.planholderdirectory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlanholderDetails extends Activity {

    protected TextView planholderName;
    protected TextView contractNo;
    protected TextView plan;
    protected TextView description;
    protected TextView effectivity;
    protected TextView dueDate;
    protected TextView quotaComm;
    protected TextView quotaNComm;
    protected TextView CBI;
    protected TextView instNo;
    protected TextView aging;
    protected TextView balance;
    protected TextView taxable;
    protected TextView insured;
    protected TextView orNo;
    protected TextView orDate;
    protected TextView collDue;
    protected TextView collAdvance;
    protected int planholderId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.planholder_details);

        planholderId = getIntent().getIntExtra("PLANHOLDER_ID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT emp._id, emp.firstName, emp.lastName, emp.contractNo, emp.plan, emp.description, emp.effectivity, emp.dueDate, emp.quotaComm, emp.quotaNComm, emp.CBI, emp.instNo, emp.aging, emp.balance, emp.taxable, emp.insured, emp.orNo, emp.orDate, emp.collDue, emp.collAdvance, emp.managerId, mgr.firstName managerFirstName, mgr.lastName managerLastName FROM planholder emp LEFT OUTER JOIN planholder mgr ON emp.managerId = mgr._id WHERE emp._id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+planholderId});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            planholderName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.planholderName);
            planholderName.setText(("Planholder: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstName")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastName")));

            contractNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contractNo);
            contractNo.setText(("LPA No.: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contractNo")));

            plan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plan);
            plan.setText(("Plan: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("plan")));

            description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
            description.setText(("Description: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

            effectivity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.effectivity);
            effectivity.setText(("Effectivity Date: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("effectivity")));

            dueDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dueDate);
            dueDate.setText(("Due Date: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dueDate")));

            quotaComm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quotaComm);
            quotaComm.setText(("Quota Comm: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("quotaComm")));

            quotaNComm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quotaNComm);
            quotaNComm.setText(("Quota NComm: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("quotaNComm")));

            CBI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CBI);
            CBI.setText(("CBI: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CBI")));

            instNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instNo);
            instNo.setText(("Inst No.: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("instNo")));

            aging = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aging);
            aging.setText(("Aging: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("aging")));

            balance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance);
            balance.setText(("Balance: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("balance")));

            taxable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taxable);
            taxable.setText(("Taxable: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("taxable")));

            insured = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.insured);
            insured.setText(("Insured: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("insured")));

            orNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orNo);
            orNo.setText(("OR Number: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("orNo")));

            orDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orDate);
            orDate.setText(("OR Date: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("orDate")));

            collDue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collDue);
            collDue.setText(("Coll Due: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("collDue")));

            collAdvance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collAdvance);
            collAdvance.setText(("Coll Advance: ")+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("collAdvance")));

        }

    }

}
```

this is my PlanholderDetails

```
package samples.planholderdirectory;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SampleLogin extends Activity {

 EditText txtUserName;
 EditText txtPassword;
 Button btnLogin;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.samplelogin);

        txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals("user") && (txtPassword.getText().toString().equals("pass"))){
           Toast.makeText(SampleLogin.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  and Start The Activity
            Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlanholderList.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
          } else{
           Toast.makeText(SampleLogin.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

   }
  });       
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        username.setText("");
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        password.setText("");

    }
}
```

this is my login activity

Comment: @DerGolem how to attach my codes? sorry this is my first time using this

Comment: do not attach your whole project. just place the interesting bits in the question. also what are you doing, are you using sqlite, etc?

Comment: Yes it is sqlite. The one that can be viewed via DDMS

Comment: Post your MainActivity.

Comment: please add you main activity and how you create the database which you want to search

Comment: I cannot post my codes it says too long. I created my database using sqlitebrowser then pushed it in my app DDMS.

Comment: @DerGolem  I was able to figure out how to attach my codes, here are my codes. I just edited my main post. Please help

Comment: @Adeeb I attached my codes, please help

Comment: @Keshav1234 I posted all of the activities in my project

Comment: @Zelldon I created my database using sqlitebrowser then pushed it in my app DDMS.

Comment: is your search method in MainActivity working?

Comment: everything I posted works when in eclipse emulator, but when emulated or installed manually in my phone, the login is the only one that works, but there is no error even in logcat, and the app doesn't force closes.

Comment: Yes it works in any computer, it also works in the phone but the database of the app is not installed together with the apk. I figured it anyway, I hardcoded the database entry in the DatabaseHelper. @Keshav1234